# kerberos authentication in python

Tags: python, authentication, kerberos

we have a database running MSSQL 2008 and I am using below Python (2.7) code to authenticate using Kerberos.

```
import urllib2
from urlparse import urlparse
from socket import gethostbyaddr  
from sspi import ClientAuth
from base64 import b64encode, b64decode


def getService(url):
    return 'host/{}'.format(
        gethostbyaddr(
            urlparse(url).netloc.split(':')[0]
        )[0][:-16]
    )

status, buff = 1, None
c = ClientAuth('Kerberos', targetspn=getService(url))
while status != 0:
    status, buff = c.authorize(buff)

    tgt = b64encode(buff[0].Buffer)
    authorization_header = \
                ("Negotiate " + tgt)
```

When I try this code in python console, getService can resolve the address correctly giving me

> host/SQLSERVER1

but when I do status, buff = c.authorize(buff) it gives me

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>      File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\win32\lib\sspi.py",
>   line 139, in authorize
>       sec_buffer_out) pywintypes.error: (-2146893053, 'InitializeSecurityContext', 'The specified target is unknown or
>   unreachable')

Why does it say The specified target is unknown or unreachable? when I can ping it and gethostbyaddr as well ? is there anyway to resolve this ?